# Looping and counting python 2d arrays

Tags: python

I have array like this:

```
[
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

I want to count value every 3 array, so the result i expected is:

```
[
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

I have no idea to loop it.

UPDATE..
this problem was solved. Thank you. I try Shijith's code this

```
if len(arr)%3==0:
    print([[sum(y) for y in zip(arr[x],arr[x+1],arr[x+2])] for x in range(0, len(arr),3)])
```

Comment: How did you came to the expected output from input?

Comment: with `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame` probably you could do something like `data[:3].sum()` `data[3:6].sum()`, `data[6:].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result = []
for i in range(int(len(a)/3)):
    result.append(np.sum(a[i*3:i*3+3], axis=0))

[array([3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pandas like this ( It splits the rows into 3, then takes the sum of each set of rows) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).sum().to_numpy().tolist()
```

output:

```
[[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

For a pure non import way:

```
combine=[] 
for x in range(3): 
   combine.append(list(sum((a[x*3:x*3+3])))) 
list(combine)
```

output:

```
[[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [numpy.sum()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) along axis=0 , for every three rows in your array.

```
import numpy as np
if len(arr)%3==0:
    print(np.array([np.sum(arr[x:x+3], axis = 0) for x in range(0, len(arr),3) ]))

[[3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

or use simple list comprehension,

```
if len(arr)%3==0:
    print([[sum(y) for y in zip(arr[x],arr[x+1],arr[x+2])] for x in range(0, len(arr),3)])

[[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: @Jhonarendra please give an upvote if you find the answer useful

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [[sum(three) for three in
    zip(arr[first], arr[first + 1], arr[first + 2])]
    for first in range(0, len(array)-len(array)%3, 3)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

[[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]